# How to make kdiff3 less verbose

Tags: ubuntu, kde, difftool

I installed `kdiff3` on `Kubuntu 22.04 LTS` and noticed it is quite chatty:

```
$ kdiff3 --version
kdiff3 1.9.5 (64 bit)
$ touch file1 file2
$ kdiff3 file1 file2
org.kde.kdiff3: "Loading A: .../file1"
org.kde.kdiff3: "Loading B: .../file2"
org.kde.kdiff3: "Diff: A <-> B"
org.kde.kdiff3: "Linediff: A <-> B"
org.kde.kdiff3: Enter: calcDiff3LineListUsingAB
org.kde.kdiff3: Leave: calcDiff3LineListUsingAB
```

These useless info messages are written to `stderr`. Can I suppress them without loosing any real error messages? I don't remember having seen them in older versions of Ubuntu.